# Reverse and split string: Python

Tags: python

I want to reverse and split a string in Python. Please suggest how?

`'this is Xing Min'` should return `['niM', 'gniX', 'si', 'siht']`.

Comment: Why the 2 upvotes? This shows 0 research effort and answers are easily found by searching

Comment: @TimCastelijns Not 2, but 4 upvotes.

Comment: @devnull I know, my comment was right after the 2nd ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
my_str[::-1].split()
```

#### Example

```
>>> s = 'Hello World'
>>> print s[::-1].split()
['dlroW'. 'olleH']

>>> s = 'this is Xing Min'
>>> print s[::-1].split()
['niM', 'gniX', 'si', 'siht']
```

Here, the `[::-1]` gets the whole string in reverse order. This is the syntax `[start:end:step]`. When you don't specify a start and end, it will deal with the whole string. When you do `[::-1]`, the `step` value is `-1` which means that the string is read in reverse.

Comment: This worked like magic, you sir are genius.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It still says Vote Up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: @user3544728, It is not the Vote Up. It is the Green Tick under the vote up/down button that is used for accepting an answer. It will look like a hollow tick which when you click becomes filled with green.

Comment: I didn't know about the `step` part of slicing, thanks for enlighting me!

Comment: I wonder why are you guys upvoting those comments? I upvoted 'em because I think they're funny

Comment: Gosh that was compact! Often lots to learn from your answers. Upvoting. :)